# multiple replace with inner join - SQL

Tags: sql, replace

It's late already so I need some help :D

```
select * 
from [Lieferant] 
inner join [BLZ] on REPLACE(Replace(Replace(Lieferant.Bankleitzahl, '.', ''),' ', ''),'-','') = BLZ.Bankleitzahl;
```

ERROR:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SWIST76' in the int data type.

The `replace` command is working on a normal select without the inner join. So I can't figure out the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You've got a field-type mismatch. one of those fields in your JOIN clause is a varchar, and the other is an int.

Comment: Bankleitzahl is of the same type in Lieferant and BLZ ?

Comment: no, but I thought it would work if I replace the symbols